# What do I get if I buy the Helicopter in Kim Kardashian: Hollywood?

Tags: kim-kardashian-hollywood

I have a car already, and the private jet. I'm just wondering what I get if I buy the helicopter.

My travel between cities is already free, so... is it just professional rating stars I will get?

Comment: You get a helicopter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Helicopter is just like a car: it costs nothing to travel between locations on the ground. You get some professional stars for buying it, but if you already have a car, there is no other benefit.